# If $τ$ is a topology and $d$ is a metric, what is $τ_d$

Tags: general-topology

If $T$ is a topology and $d$ is a distance, what is $T_d$

The definition of a topology is:

- Both the empty set and X are elements of $τ$
- Any union of elements of $τ$ is an element of $τ$
- Any intersection of finitely many elements of τ is an element of $τ$.

Since a topology implies the notion of open sets in $τ$ I understand why you need the notion of distance. So I understand that $τ_d$ means it's a topology using the metric $d$.

But in the case where we write the topology: $τ$ without any precision on the metric, does it just mean that the metric we use is obvious?

Comment: It may also mean that there is no metric to begin with

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how do you determine whether a set is open or not without a metric?

Comment: A set is open iff it is $\in \tau$

Answer (score 3):

If you have a metric space $(X,d)$, then you may define a topology on $X$ by postulating that $U \subseteq X$ is open if and only if for every $x \in U$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for each $y$ with $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ we have $y \in U$. You can then go on to prove that this is a topology.

However, it is perfectly possible to have a topology *without* a metric. For a simple example, take any set $X$. Then there is a topology on $X$ where the *only* open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself. You can show easily that this satisfies the axioms of a topology, yet -- if $X$ has more than 1 element -- there is no metric which gives this topology.

Thus, in this sense, topologies are more general than metrics.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are quite confused, and need to do some basic reading.

Every metric space is a topological space -- the distance function of the metric space gives us a way to construct the open sets that constitute the topology. If the distance function is $d$, it would be reasonable to use $\tau_d$ to denote the topology derived from $d$.

On the other hand there are topologies that are **not** derived from a metric. Saying it another way, you do not need a metric in order to define the open sets of a topology.